# OpenVPN: client to LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, openvpn

I set up an OpenVPN server on a Debian machine under my router. I port forward all UDP 1194 connections to the server, and I am able to connect successfully from my windows machine using the OpenVPN client. However, I seem to be getting an IP address that is not on the LAN of the VPNserver. I would like to be able to access all the devices on the Debian server's LAN. I am not able to ping any of them, except for some reason I am able to ping my Proxmox server on the LAN. I am also not able to ping the server's other IP as seen under tun0. Here is my server's configuration and the output of the VPN connection which gives my windows machine an IP of 10.8.0.6.
[image: Server ifconfig]

[image: VPN connection]

Why would this be happening and what should I do to possibly fix it?

Thank you

Comment: A couple of things I see from your logs.  First, are you running the OpenVPN client as an admin?  You're getting "access denied" errors when trying to setup routes to the VPN.  Also, it looks like your configuration is pushing some extra routes that are probably not needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm running as admin on the client.

Comment: How would I go about fixing those errors and removing the extra routes? Thank you.

Comment: The access denied errors, you would need to make sure the OpenVPN client has permissions to modify routes.  The extra routes are probably coming from the server configuration.  Can you share your config files?

Comment: By the way here  is the tutorial I was using, where I obtained the shell script that set up the server for me. When you say config files do you mean the .opvn file that has the cert and key too? Thank you again             [here]: https://vpnreviewer.com/openvpn-howto-debian-ubuntu-vps

Comment: Just to confirm, when you start the client you are right clicking on the icon and selecting "Run as Administrator", right?  On the server, the config file is probably `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`.

Comment: Actually, when you said run as administrator I thought you meant login in as admin. When I ran it, it had asked me permission to run it, but then I tried to run as a administrator and it worked. I can now access machines on my LAN. However, while I am connected my computer cannot access the internet, i.e. cannot access websites. Is that suppose to happen? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Again, that depends on your server configuration.  Look for a line in the server config like `push "redirect-gateway def1"`.  You can remove/comment out this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server's VPN IP is `10.8.0.1` and your client's VPN IP is correctly being set to `10.8.0.6`.  The reason they do not *appear* to be in the same network is because your VPN server is using the default **topology** which is `net30`.  This is clearly explained in the [OpenVPN Manual](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals.html) under the heading **--topology**

The reason for the `Access is denied` errors (as per your log) is usually because the client OpenVPN is not *running as Administrator* and so does not have the necessary prinileges to assign the IP or change the routing table.